# wso2 vfs FileInnound Move AFter Process to several folders

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

Do you know if there is a way to use transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess parameter of a File InboundEndpoint in order to move the processed file to several folders (with separator, multiple entries...)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a deeper look in the source code (https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation/blob/master/components/inbound-endpoints/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/inbound/endpoint/protocol/file/FilePollingConsumer.java) it looks not possible so I'll have to create a copy of the file after reading it.